# Restrict user access to several actions in function

Tags: users

I have a function, that returns statistics for the user:

```
function module_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items["statistics"] = array(
    'page callback' => 'module_statistics',
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function module_statistics($group_id, $user_id = NULL) {
  global $user;
  if ($user_id == NULL) {
    $user_id = $user->uid;
  }
  $result = module_statistics_table($group_id, $user_id);
  print $result;
}
```

I want only the administrator to have access to this function with $user_id != NULL. So the user will be unable to watch someone elses statistics. I have an access argument 'admin tasks' for the admin. How to do the else statement:

```
if ($user_id == NULL) {
  $user_id = $user->uid;
}
else {
  if($user has no access to 'admin tasks') {
    return HTTP 403 Forbidden status code;
    exit from function;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I assume correctly that this is going to called/accessed like this...

```
www.yourhost.com/statistics/group_id[/user_id]
```

eg

```
www.yourhost.com/statistics/19/64
```

or

```
www.yourhost.com/statistics/19
```

...then you could do something along the lines of...

```
function module_statistics($group_id, $user_id = NULL) {
  global $user;

  if ($user_id == NULL) {
    $user_id=$user->uid;
  }

  if ($user_id==$user->uid || user_access('admin tasks')) {
    return module_statistics_table($group_id, $user_id);
  } else {
    return MENU_ACCESS_DENIED;
  }
}
```

which if my pre-espresso logic is working will call your function if the user's uid matches what s/he is asking for OR they are they admin.  If not, return an access denied message.

Answer (score 2):

In your `hook_menu` call you can use different *access arguments*, to make sure only administrators access the callback function. For example,

```
'access arguments' => array('administer users'), // usually Administrators have this permissions
```

If users with some other roles try to access the menu, they'll get the **Access Denied** message by default.

If you want your users to access the function and restrict only certain part, you can check the user role in that case:

```
if ($user_id == NULL) {
  $user_id = $user->uid;
}
else {
  if(in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles))) {
    //apply your exit function logic here
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is, that the users should also access this function, so they could view their own statistics. But not the statistics of the other users.

Comment: @user4035 - you can check the role, see the edited answer.

Comment: Forget the in_array(). You want user_access(), which is the Drupal Way. :-) http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_access/7

Answer (score 2):

From your code, I take you are always expecting the group ID is passed, as your page callback doesn't assign a default value to `$group_id`. If this is the case, I would rather suggest the following code.

```
function module_menu() {
  $items['statistics/%/%user_uid_optional_load'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'module_statistics',
    'access callback' => 'module_statistics_access',
    'access arguments' => array(2),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

function module_statistics_access($account) {
  return ($GLOBALS['user']->uid == $account->uid || user_access('admin tasks'));
}

function module_statistics($group_id, $account) {
  print module_statistics_table($group_id, $account);
}
```

Notice that:

- It should be only the access callback that decides if the user has access to a page.
- With the code I wrote, `$account` is the user object for the currently logged-in user, when the user ID is not passed as argument, or the user object for the passed user ID when the user ID is passed in the URL.